# A "Resource bundle" for persisting other then localization data

Tags: java, properties, dictionary, settings, resourcebundle

I need system similar to [`ResourceBundles`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) except that I will not use it for localization. Basically, I need to store several versions of settings. One version of that settings is String-to-String map, that can be represented by `Properties` file. These settings versions must be easily persisted to file system inside application .jar (alike  [`PropertyResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PropertyResourceBundle.html)).

The idea is to have different versions of application settings (settings profiles), represented by key-value pairs of type string, that can be chosen from at application start up based of user decision. Again these are not language versions so `ResourceBundle` (according to its javadoc) is not the right way to implement it.

Any easy way how to do that without implementing the whole think myself? Please do not suggest third-party it should only use Java SE classes.

---

**Edit:** I forgot to mention one important detail. It would be hard for me to get stream like this: `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/your/resource/here");`. That is because the project that would contain properties file is compiled by Ant and used as a dynamically loaded library in different GUI projects that actually run. I might have all properties files in fixed project folder but since `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` returns context of GUI project and I do not know where in that project was the .jar with property file placed by Ant I do not know what to use as `"/your/resource/here"`.

Comment: How about just using `java.util.Properties`? Load the property files according to your current profile and reload as soon as that profile changes.

Comment: That came to my mind but what I like about `ResourceBundle` is that it finds `.properties` files location automatically for me. If I was to manually load `.property` file according to current profile there would be a quite a bit of messy code finding the location of `.properties` file according to location of my application so I could create `FileInputStream` and load the file into `Properties`.

Comment: But it may be a good thing to have a convention where your profile settings need to be stored. So you don't have to look for it everywhere.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker Please see my edit. It is explained there why placing it all to fixed folder/package in project would not help.

Answer (score 2):

I might have misunderstood the question however seems to me you can easily do something like this:

```
InputStream inputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/your/resource/here");
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(inputStream);
```

This will be safe in a Java EE environment as well and you can call you anytime you need if you want settings to change.

Update: as long as the resource is on the classpath you should be able to find it without knowing the full path of the resource as well.

Comment: Good point - I forgot to mention one important detail. The resource will be in class path (or rather the project with the resource will be dynamically loaded in runtime), but I do not know where exactly it will be. Can I still find it without specifying full path? See edit to my question for details.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically loaded JAR? If the property is in the JAR file that is referenced by the GUI project then it's still on the classpath and you should be able to get it. You will need to place them somewhere though. Also can you change the Ant script? You should place the resources in the root of the JAR file so you don't have to reference any directories and just use the file name, of course that depends on you controlling the generating of the JAR file in Ant.